# Trouble with pointing to strings / element of structs. w/ C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

Sorry if my question is unclear, my vocabulary isn't that great when it comes to c and pointers and such.

I have a simple program that takes a header `data.h` which contains the following struct.

```
#ifndef MENU_H_
#define MENU_H_

typedef struct student{
    int gpa;
    float tuitionFees;
    int numCourses;
}student;

typedef struct employee{
    float salary;
    int serviceYears;
    int level;
}employee;

typedef struct person{
    char *firstName[20];
    char familyName[20];
    char telephoneNum[20];
    int type; // 0 = student / 1 = employee;
    union{
        employee e;
        student s;
    };
}newPerson;


#endif /* MENU_H_ */
```

I have a `main.c` that contains nothing but this so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "menu.h"
#include "data.h"

    main(){

        //printMenu();
        menu();
    }
```

And then most of the code is in here, `menu.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "menu.h"
#include "data.h"
#include "uni_personal.h"

int menu(){
    int num = 0;
    newPerson person[MAX_PERSONS];
    int option;
    printf("\n\tPlease choose one of the following options to continue (0-9): ");
    scanf("%d", &option );
    printf("\n\tYou selected %d\n", option);

    if (option == 0){                               //program will close
            printf("\tProgram will now close.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    if (option == 1){ //program will ask for name input
        addRecord(&person[num], &num);
        printf("\n\tThe name is: %s", *person[num].firstName);
        printf("\n\tThe number is suppose to be 99 if done right == %d\n", person[num].type);
    }
}

void addRecord(newPerson *pers, int *num){
    setStudent(pers, 0);
    addName(pers, num);
}

void addName(newPerson *pers, int *num){
    printf("\tEnter Name: ");
    scanf("%20s", *pers->firstName);
}

void setStudent(newPerson *pers, int *num){
    pers->type = 99; // Test number to see if pointed correctly
}

int changeNum(int *num){
    *num = 50;
    return *num;
}



void printMenu(){
    printf("\n\n\n============================================================\n");
    printf("\t STUDENT/EMPLOYEE RECORDS:\n");
    printf("\t\t1. Add a new record\n");
    printf("\t\t2. Print Student List\n");
    printf("\t\t0. Quit\n");
}
```

Basically I'd like to have a function that is used to ask the user for a name via scanf, and then using the string inputted, make it the person.firstName. However the method I'm using, it returns null when I try to print it out, if I change "%s" to "%p" in the printf, it would return nil instead.

Using the same method, I was able to successful set my int `type`, but I'm struggling to figure out how to append the user input string into my person.firstName element.

Could someone point out what I'm doing that is wrong? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have declared firstName as an array of 20 pointers to char.  I suspect you want a simple array of 20 chars.  Drop the * in that declaration (like familyName).  In the scanf call for firstName, just pass the buffer, so again remove the "*".